# Using kinterbasdb with py2exe

Tags: python, firebird, py2exe, kinterbasdb

I'm trying to create executable program with py2exe. I get the following error message when kinterbasdb is imported:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AlarmReporter.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "kinterbasdb\__init__.pyo", line 119, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 98, in load_module
ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading kinterbasdb\_kinterbasdb.pyd
```

Here's my very basic setup.py for py2exe:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys


setup(
        options={'py2exe': dict(bundle_files=1, optimize=2)},
        console=['AlarmReporter.py'],
        zipfile=None,
)
```

I'm having problem understanding the error message and have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to exclude libfbclient dll

[Error while transforming .py to .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339583/error-while-transforming-py-to-exe)

If that doesn't work , try to use the new fdb driver (the future replacement of kinterbasdb)
http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.firebird.python/104
(it doesn't need compiling only the libfbclient.dll)

Another option is to use the pure driver that doesn't need no dll and no c generated binary 
https://github.com/nakagami/pyfirebirdsql

But you will use it at your own risk ;)