# run py2exe under windows 7, can not excecute file under windows XP

Tags: python, windows, pygtk, py2exe

I created a exe-file from my Python+Gtk application using py2exe. With windwos 7 it works, but I can't get it running under windwos XP. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "debug4iConnect.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "startApp.pyc", line 1, in <module>
  File "gtk\__init__.pyc", line 40, in <module>
  File "gtk\_gtk.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "gtk\_gtk.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata.
```

I tried to find missing dlls using dependency-walker and recieved this messages:

```
LoadLibraryA("c:\......\zlib.pyd") returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato (126).

LoadLibraryExA("c:\.....\gtk._gtk.pyd", 0x00000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).

"Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata" means: Impossible to find specified procedure. 
"Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato" means: Impossible to find the specified module.
```

This thread seams to be a similar problem, but the solution doesn't work for me: [Py2exe - win32api.pyc ImportError DLL load failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979486/py2exe-win32api-pyc-importerror-dll-load-failed)

Has someone an idea what I could do?

UPDATE:
I tried dependencywalker again and found some missing dlls:

```
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-MANAGEMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-MANAGEMENT-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-WINSVC-L1-1-0.DLL
CRYPTBASE.DLL
MSJAVA.DLL,
```

I added them, and now I get this error:

```
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "CtfImmCoUninitialize") called from "c:\windows\system32
\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B279F and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "CtfImmLastEnabledWndDestroy") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B27DC and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "CtfImmSetCiceroStartInThread") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B281F and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "CtfImmIsCiceroStartedInThread") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B2864 and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "CtfImmIsCiceroEnabled") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B28A9 and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "CtfImmIsTextFrameServiceDisabled") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B28E5 and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "CtfImmEnterCoInitCountSkipMode") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B292C and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "CtfImmLeaveCoInitCountSkipMode") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B2972 and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "ImmGetDefaultIMEWnd") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B29B6 and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "ImmReleaseContext") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B29EF and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "ImmNotifyIME") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B2A29 and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "ImmSetConversionStatus") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B2A5C and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "ImmGetConversionStatus") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B2A9A and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "ImmGetProperty") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B2AD6 and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "ImmGetOpenStatus") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B2B0A and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "ImmGetContext") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B2B40 and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "ImmSetOpenStatus") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B2B75 and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "ImmInstallIMEA") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B2BAC and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "ImmGetDescriptionA") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B2BE2 and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "ImmGetDescriptionW") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B2C1A and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "ImmGetIMEFileNameA") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B2C52 and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "ImmGetIMEFileNameW") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B2C8A and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
GetProcAddress(0x00000000, "ImmSetHotKey") called from "c:\windows\system32\MSCTF.DLL" at address 0x746B3168 and returned NULL. Error: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata (127).
```

When I execute the application I get the error:

```
Fatal Python error: Interpreter not initialized (version mismatch?)
```

When I delete zlib.pyd again I get the `ImportError` above. I found out that my zlib.pyd is from python2.4 and there is no zlib.pyd for 2.7 anymore, it shoul be included in python27.dll. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

solved: I set
`"bundle_files": 3` and `"skip_archive": True`
now it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find the missing dll.

May be you need to install the Visual Studio redistribuables on the XP machine.

Comment: Hi, the output of dependency walker I postet above, I installed Visual Studio redistributables, without this the application wasn't able to start, i get only a message "could not start application"

Comment: Sorry for dependency walker. Did you look at http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyGTK ?

Comment: I tried dependency walker again and found some other things, I edited the main post,
Yes, I built it under windows7 following the py2exe tutorial on py2exe.org

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. For me the solution was to exclude the `MSWSOCK.dll` and  `POWRPROF.dll` libraries from the collection:

```
setup(
    # other options ommited...
    options={
        "py2exe":{
            "dll_excludes": ["POWRPROF.dll", "MSWSOCK.dll"]
        }
    },
)
```

This also got rid of all the MS_API_*.dll files.